# Is memoizing possible without side effects

Tags: f#, functional-programming, memoization, side-effects

I have some F# code that caches results for future lookup. My understanding is that dictionaries and other data structures that you add to require side effects. (i.e. changing the state of the dictionary) Is this correct? Is this considered impure or is this still in the model of side effect free computation.

```
let rec fib =
    let dict = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<_,_>()
    fun n ->
        match dict.TryGetValue(n) with
        | true, v -> v
        | false, _ -> 
            let fibN =
                match n with
                | 0 | 1 -> n
                | _ -> fib (n - 1) + fib(n - 2)
            dict.Add(n, fibN)
            fibN
```

Comment: My F# might be a little rusty, but I don't see how successive calls to `fib` could be sharing an instance of `dict` to provide the caching. Wouldn't each call of the function get its own `dict` instance?

Comment: @CoderDennis Its a closure over the dict. The word fib is bound to the lamda function that does the logic. Each call shares the dict binding

Comment: The problem with side-effects is scope and the ability to reason about how the system is functioning.  This is why global variables are the ultimate evil.  The fib function itself has no side effects.  The fact that it has side effects in the implementation is irrelevant.

Comment: @mydogisbox wouldn't dict.TryGetValue(n) be susceptible to side effects. Not in this example but in general. Because the state of some place in memory affects the run time value. If for example I stored the wrong value in dict on the first call but returned the correct value. The second time I call it I would get the wrong value.

Comment: @TomDDD: You can't store a wrong value in the dict if the (actual) function is pure, because there's only one value the function can produce for given arg.

Comment: @mydogisbox suppose my call to dict.Add went like this. `dict.Add(n, fibN - 1)` Then the first time I call `fib 1` I would get 1 the second call would give me 0. I have come to the conclusion that this does have side effects. Its just behaving as expected because the structure is correct.

Comment: @TomDDD: Also, I'd suggest moving the memoizing bits into a dedicated higher-order memoize function. By doing that, you actually can make the memoized function pure, and memoization an implementation detail. The code you posted, where those two concerns are tangled together, is not as simple to reason about as it could be.

Comment: @scrwtp I think this is what I was getting at. Its pretty easy to make a memoize function that takes a function and yields a memoized copy. It would be like the inner function (fib) would be pure. It has no idea what a side affect is. But since you're calling the memoized one it then knows how to reduce calls to the pure function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To restate what was mentioned in the comments, you can extract memoization into a higher order function that would return a memoized version of the function passed in as an argument:

```
let memoize f =
    let dict = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<_,_>()
    fun x ->
        match dict.TryGetValue(n) with
        | true, v -> v
        | false, _ ->
             let v = f x
             dict.Add(x, v)
             v
```

By doing that, you actually can make the memoized function pure, and memoization an implementation detail. The code you posted, where those two concerns are tangled together, is not as simple to reason about as it could be.

Note that memoizing a recursive function is a little tricky - you need to structure the function to memoize in a way that lends itself to memoization.

A separate issue here are the concurrency problems you can run into. To combat those, you could either have a lock around the `dict.Add`:

```
...
let v = f x
lock dict <| fun () ->
    if not <| dict.ContainsKey(x) then
       dict.Add(x, v)
v
```

or instead of `Dictionary` have a `ref` cell holding a `Map` (in which case any concurrency issues you might have are still there, but are no longer catastrophic in nature).

Answer (score 1):

A memoized function stores the result so it doesn't have to calculate the result on subsequent calls with the same arguments.  The fact of storing the result is a side effect, and it is also the defining property of a memoized function.  I therefore conclude that the answer to your question is "no."

To address your comment about storing the wrong value in the dict; yes, you're right, but there's another problem that doesn't involve incorrect results.  The Dictionary class is not thread-safe.  If two threads try to read from and/or write to the dictionary at the same time, you will likely get an exception.  For example:

```
let data = [| 1 .. 20 |]
let fibs = data |> Array.Parallel.map fib
```

I didn't get any exception when I ran this, several times, in F# interactive, but with certain changes, I got a System.ArgumentException:

> An item with the same key has already been added.

The changes were these; in each case, I got the exception on the first or second try:

- Instrument the function to print diagnostic information using `printfn`
- Change the numeric type to `uint64` (removing `printfn` diagnostics)
- Change the numeric type to `float` (i.e., System.Double)
- Change the numeric type to `bigint`